# How to undo changes in the commands-history?

Tags: bash, command-history, readline

In UNIX systems you can press top and bottom arrows to navigate through the previous commands. This is extremely handy.

Sometimes, I go up and find a command that I want to use again, but with some variations. If I do such changes, then I don't have a way to get the original command back, unless I check it in `history`.

Is there any way to "undo" the changes to the command in the history accessed through keys?

My current workaround is to prepend a `#` to the command.  This way the current command is performed as a comment, so nothing happens. Then, I can browse again through the commands with the keys. The problem is that the command I was using may be veeeery far away in the list, so going up again two hundred times is a bit . Control + R is not a solution either, since I may not remember exactly what I was looking for.

#### Example

I typed the following "50 commands ago":

```
ls -l /etc/httpd/conf/
```

Now I went up to that line and changed it to

```
ls -l /etc/init.d/
```

but did not press enter. Now, I want to get to the `ls -l /etc/httpd/conf/` again.

#### My environment

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

Comment: That the command history is changed is likely a (mis-)feature of the shell you are using. In `ksh`, for example, you can edit history entries and invoke them without deleting the "previous version" of the entry; you have all invoked commands available.

Comment: With "it changes" I mean that: given a previous command that I changed after reaching it with the arrows, if I go up and down with the arrows, the old command won't show the way it was, but the way I modified it. Of course, if I type "enter" performing a command, that old command will be as it was initially; but this is precisely what I am trying to avoid and looking for a way to "reset" the command to its initial value.

Comment: Also in this case, `ksh`'s behaviour differs here, it seems. And your history edit options also depend on the choosen editing mode. In `ksh`'s vi-mode, for example, the old entry is not overwritten, and I can also issue an undo command, like in `vi`, with 'u'.

Comment: Uhms, this sounds very promising. I am now working in Bash and currently not considering to change to `ksh`, but it is good to know such thing exists there.

Comment: I'd like to know where bash stores recent command history before writing to the history file when the shell is closed.  It may help in determining if this is possible.  Anybody? I thought it might be in a one of the shell variables, but don't have time to pore over the manual right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131657/is-there-any-way-to-undo-a-bash-history-modification

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As long as you've edited a history entry but not pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> yet, to go back to the original entry, repeatedly press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> — the `undo` command — until it doesn't make any further change. You're back to the original entry.

Comment: Just `Ctrl`+`-` works as well.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus No, it doesn't, not from bash's perspective. Maybe your terminal emulator converts `Ctrl+-` to `Ctrl-_` — but that would be specific to your keyboard layout, and not all terminal emulators do this.

Comment: Ah you're right. It works different in different terminals. gnome-terminal zooms out with `Ctrl`+`-` whereas xfce4-terminal undos

Comment: You troubleshoot key bindings with Bash built-in `bind -p | less`. And define a binding with: `bind '"\C-_": undo'`.

Answer (score 10):

[Revert to the original command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#index-revert_002dline-_0028M_002dr_0029) when you've have made multiple changes to the line:

```
revert-line (M-r) 
    Undo all changes made to this line. This is like 
executing the undo command enough times to get back to the beginning.
```

`M` is the meta key, which is <kbd>alt</kbd+<kbd>r</kbd> for me.</kbd>

---

### Gratuitous, Yet Helpful Info

When you *have* executed a command like OP had previously done (it happens), there is nothing to "undo" because the commands are handled and remembered by the [GNU Readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline) library and are [not written to `$HISTFILE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html) until the shell exits. The reason I mention this is because you can't just `grep` the `$HISTFILE` like one might expect and it may not be ideal to exit the shell.

So here are a couple of options to save you from scrolling back through all previous readline commands.

**If you remember some of the command**, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and type what you remember to [search through previous commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Searching.html) containing that string. Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> again will display the next most recent, searching backwards.

For example, type `ls -l` then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> as many times as it takes to find the previous command you seek. If you scroll past it, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+s will search forward from the current position.

**The `fc` bash builtin command** is helpful to list the index numbers alongside previous readline commands.

`fc -l -100` will list the previous 100 commands in readline.

Additionally, if OP knows he's looking for a previous `ls -l` command, he could pipe the output to `grep` such as: `fc -l -100 | grep 'ls -l'`

This should output a list of previous `ls -l` commands preceded by an index number. The output looks like this:
`2065    ls -l`

Now you can use the event designator `!n` where `n` is the index number. In this example, executing `!2065` will expand to `ls -l`.

---

Although it doesn't help after the fact, anyone looking to preserve the recent command history when modifying previous commands should see the `HISTORY EXPANSION` section of `man bash`. Here are some alternative methods for modifying old commands without overwriting the history.

The `Event Designators` section shows how you can easily edit string from the most recently used command.

```
^string1^string2^
              Quick  substitution.  Repeat the previous command, replacing string1 with string2.  Equivalent to
              ``!!:s/string1/string2/'' (see Modifiers below).
```

Example:

```
$ echo foo
foo 
$ ^foo^bar
echo bar
bar
```

The most recent commands will now show:

```
echo foo
echo bar
```

The above example also explains how to use `sed` to replace a string in an event designator.

```
!-n    Refer to the current command minus n.
```

So if 3 commands up in the history is `echo foo` then you would use:
`!-3:s/foo/bar`

Note that event designators will appear in your history as the command executed, in this case `echo bar`. It will not appear in the history as `!-3:s/foo/bar`.

Just throwing that out there as it seems closely related, even if it is more of a "don't do" than the "undo" solution OP is looking for.

Comment: This is nice, many thanks for the detailed information. I am accepting Gilles's answer since it does exactly what I am looking for, whereas here you assume I know many things about the command I want to redo, which is not always the case.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It would be great if that undo feature were extended to previously I entered commands somehow.

Answer (score 3):

The readline variable [`revert-all-at-newline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#index-revert_002dall_002dat_002dnewline), available since Bash 4.0/Readline 6.0, accomplishes nearly the desired effect.

If set, then hitting enter on any line (could be a different command, or even an empty line) will revert any history entries that were edited but not executed (as in the example in the question).

This can be set with

```
set revert-all-at-newline on
```

in `~/.inputrc`.

or

```bash
bind 'set revert-all-at-newline on'
```

in `~/.bashrc`.